# NO SQL,ORIENTDB

Tags: orientdb

I have already inserted record in OrientDB using `insert` query. But I forgot  to save it. Now I wanted that query in OrientDB.Is there any ways to get that query back?

I am using OrientDB. I wrote the `insert` statement to insert the data in the class(table). Now I want all the insert statement querys back in OrientDB itself.

I want to reinsert the data using same query.

The query will be in the following format.

```
Insert into TABLE name()values();
```

I wrote some 100 queries using insert statement. But I lost all. Is it possible take the back up of all the queries I wrote so far in OrientDB.

Comment: Could you explain better what you need?, thx

Comment: I am using OrientDB (no sql database).I wrote the  insert statement to insert the data in the class(table).now i want all the insert statement querys back in orientdb itself.i want to reinsert the data using same query.The query will be in the following format.Insert into TABLE name()values(); i wrote some 100 querys using insert statement.But i lost all.Is it possible take the back up of all the querys i wrote so far in Orientdb.

Answer (score 0):

If you have logged yor queries in OrientDB log, you can try to get by there. When you run a query by studio, you have a history run queries. If you have deleted the history or clean the log, you can't retrieve them